# Arguments via method in controller

Tags: php

Frameworks like CodeIgniter does have this:

```
public function index($arg1, $arg2) {
    echo $arg1;
}
```

where $arg1, $arg2 is something like. index.php/controller/index/arg1/arg2.

I am wondering how this works behind the wall? The code within these frameworks are like a jungle. I'm lost.

Comment: in codeigniter, you can find it in `system/core/router.php`

Comment: would you like to implement this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to configure your web server (Apache or so) to execute for all the requests (uri's) the same PHP (also known as front controller).

Then, in your front controller you'll need to parse the uri (http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) and make it match one of your routing rules (using regex for example).

Take a look at https://github.com/symfony/Routing (or read Charlie's comment).

In the case of **index.php/controller/index/arg1/arg2** you **don't need to configure the web server** (just get the **PATH_INFO**):

```
<?php

class Controller {

    public function indexAction($a, $b) {

        return "$a & $b";

    }
}

$path = trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/');
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$controllerName = ucfirst($parts[0]);
$actionName = $parts[1] . 'Action';

$controller = new $controllerName();

echo $controller->$actionName($parts[2], $parts[3]);
```

Obviously this example is toooooooo basic. There is more stuff, like route definition, method reflection to get the names of the method arguments and a lot more, so please get into the source code some nice framework (like Symfony2!!!!).